# Is the song title "A 1000 Times" redundant?

Tags: redundancy

You might or might not know this song "A 1000 Times" by Hamilton Leithauser + Rostam, but the main concern here is that *1000* itself is *a/one thousand* already, therefore is this song title redundant in words?

Or am I wrong in some way? It's a popular studio-released song, how could such error be possible?

Comment: The title looks wrong to me.  As you point out, "1000" is already pronounced "one thousand" or "a thousand", so "A one thousand times" or "A a thousand times" is just wrong.  However: this is popular music, not a grammar textbook.  It's written to look and sound interesting, not to be strictly correct.

Comment: If the choice is between the ungrammatical "a one thousand" on the one hand, and on the other, understanding 1000 to represent "thousand", I would err on the side of the grammatical and say 1000 is a bit of typographical "cleverness".   "A thousand times" is a common enough phrase, as in "If I've asked you once, I've asked you a thousand times, don't leave your _________ in the ________".

Comment: I think many people simply wouldn't notice the "orthographic error". But really it's on a par with "old skool" dj mixes or *Inglourious Basterds* (the people who came up with all of them knew perfectly well they were "breaking the rules" - they just like to live dangerously). Whatever - this isn't really about "correct" English. It's about playing with language.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with ***a 1000-hour trip across the world***?

Comment: @Clare no cuz in that case "a" is for "a trip" with the modifier "1000-hour" to indicate duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good observation! Got me digging a bit on the Internet because I actually never paid attention to the exact pronunciation of this.

Many websites (without any clear sign of credibility) say *1000* is pronounced as *a/one thousand*, but I was not sure if just *thousand* would suffice.

This could be the most reliable [source](http://www.macmillandictionaries.com/MED-Magazine/July2004/21-Language-Awareness-Numbers-UK.htm) I could find, in which *1000* is said to be pronounced as *a/one thousand*; and the website does not provide any alternative. I've decided to trust this source and therefore come to conclusion: yes you are right, the song title has redundancy error.

Comment: He pays me '100 per day: or 'a 100 per day'?

Comment: The former, obviously. Otherwise you could say "a 100-dollar check per day"

Answer (score 3):

If I saw the title written simply as "1000 Times", I would read it as "One Thousand Times". By starting with "A", it changes that. But you can't write "A 000 Times". That wouldn't work either. So unless you actually want to write out the word, "Thousand", the only option left is "A 1000 Times".

Comment: Yeah you have a point, but every time I look at that title my mind always reads "a one thousand times" and it was quite troubling.